# Parsing XML with inner nodes?

Tags: c#, parsing, linq-to-xml

I have a XML file like the below:

```
 <clients>
  <client>
    <id>YYYY</id>
    <name>XXXX</name>
    <desc>ZZZZ</desc>
    <trade_info>
      <tab_list>
       <data>
         <tab>book 123</tab>
       </data>
       <data>
         <tab>cook 321</tab>
       </data>
      </tab_list>
      <buy_price_rate>200</buy_price_rate>
    </trade_info>
  </client>
 </clients>
```

I need to extract from it `id, name, desc` and from the inner node trade_info I need `data/tab, buy_price_rate`.

So initially I was thinking of this:

```
    var query = from node in doc.Descendants("client")
                select new
                {
                    client = new
                    {
                        Id = node.Element("id").Value,
                        Name = node.Element("name").Value,
                        Desc = node.Element("desc").Value
                    },

                    trade = from n in node.Descendants("trade_info")
                               select new
                               {
                                   Id = n.Element("tab_list").Element("data").Element("tab").Value,
                                   Buy = n.Element("buy_price_rate").Value
                               }
                };

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            writeXML.WriteStartElement("tradelist_template");
            writeXML.WriteAttributeString("client_id", item.client.Id);
            foreach (var trade in item.trade)
            {
                writeXML.WriteStartElement("tradelist");
                writeXML.WriteAttributeString("item_id", trade.Id);
                writeXML.WriteEndElement();
            }
            writeXML.WriteEndElement();
        }
```

But it does not seem to work and im not sure on how to debug it.

From the first error I got, Null Expection I belive it may be coming from the `node.Descendants("trade_info")` as some clients have no trade_info at all.

I also belive there is some comming from:

```
Id = n.Element("tab_list").Element("data").Element("tab").Value,
Buy = n.Element("buy_price_rate").Value
```

As sometimes they dont have items on the list or buy_price_rate.

- How do I check within my query
  wether it is null or not to secure it
- Is my query ok for what I want ?
- What should I change ? Advices ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could also do this....

```
  var list = from item in doc.Descendants("client")
             let tradeinfoelement = item.Element("trade_info")
             select new
             {
               Client = new
               {
                 Id = (string)item.Element("id"),
                 Name = (string)item.Element("name"),
                 Desc = (string)item.Element("desc")
               },
               TradeInfo = new
               {
                 BuyPrice = tradeinfoelement.Element("buy_price_rate")  != null ? (int?)tradeinfoelement.Element("buy_price_rate") : null,
                 Tabs = tradeinfoelement.Descendants("tab") != null ? tradeinfoelement.Descendants("tab").Select(t => (string)t).ToList() : null
               }
             };
```

The main thing is to map out what your wrapping class looks like and work out what your defaults should be in case there is no data for the specific property you will map. (I chose nulls in this example)

Answer (score 2):

Your value doc should of type `XElement` then you can select `id` like

```
var query = from el in doc.Descendants(XName.Get("id"))
 select el.Value;
```

using `XName` is not necessary you can just use a string, but is useful if your xml has namespaces on some of the elements.

Comment: my doc is `XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);`, you reply seems a bit vague to me but thanks.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

Can you change the `trade` part of your query to:

```
trade = from n in node.Descendants("trade_info")
  select new
  {
    Id = (n.XPathSelectElement("tab_list/data/tab") == null) ? null : n.XPathSelectElement("tab_list/data/tab").Value,
    Buy = (n.Element("buy_price_rate") == null) ? null : n.Element("buy_price_rate").Value
  }
```

..?

(you'll need to add `using System.Xml.XPath`)

Comment: It worked well just by using the null verification without using XPath but using XPath it seems easier. Thanks.

Comment: Yep with a construct like `n.Element("tab_list").Element("data").Element("tab").Value` I thought it would be painful to check for nulls at each step of the way, easier to use XPath